# How to fill the blank in choropleth in r ? ggplot2 and maps

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, choropleth

Anyone can tell me how do I fill the blank field in my choropleth? I have attached a picture for the choropleth I created.Thanks a lot!

I noticed the statename in two tables do not match, but I am not able to change the statename in my raw data.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
**#Data looks like this:**

aggrev2015<-data.frame(
statename=c("alabama","alaska","arizona","arkansas","california","colorado","connecticut","delaware","florida","georgia","hawaii","idaho","illinois","indiana","iowa","kansas","kentucky","louisiana","maine","maryland","massachusetts","michigan", "minnesota","mississippi","missouri","montana","nebraska","nevada","new hampshire","new jersey","new mexico","new york","north carolina","north dakota","ohio","oklahoma", "oregon","pennsylvania","rhode island","south carolina","south dakota","tennessee","texas","utah","vermont","virginia","washington","west virginia","wisconsin","wyoming"),
  revenue=runif(50,min=100,max=9000))

state_df <- map_data("state")
colnames(state_df)<-c("long","lat","group","order","statename","subregion")

choropleth <- merge(aggrev2015,state_df, by = "statename")

ggplot(choropleth, aes(long, lat, group = statename)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = revenue))
```

[image: choropleth]

Comment: you have not attached any picture, not have you really provided any data for anyone to work with. I would suggest making your "alaska/hawaii" question a separate one and have you done _any_ research on adding HI & AK to a US map? Did you come across http://rud.is/b/2014/11/16/moving-the-earth-well-alaska-hawaii-with-r/ in said research?

Comment: thank you for adding the picture link. i've expanded it. after seeing that map, you may be better off using the `choroplethr` package (it's in CRAN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance your problem seems related to states that have islands. Rather than debug that, I'll follow up on @hrbrmstr's suggestion of using choroplethr:

```
library(choroplethr)
library(choroplethrMaps)

data(df_pop_state)
state_choropleth(df_pop_state)
```

[image]

You can see more documention on creating state choropleths with the choroplethr package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/choroplethr/vignettes/b-state-choropleth.html), and the package has an [email course](http://arilamstein.com/free-course) as well.

For state choropleths, I think that the main advantage of the package over doing it yourself is demonstrated in the above vignette: It makes exploratory data analysis much easier. For example, changing the scale or zooming becomes as easy as setting parameters on a function. The package also includes AK and HI as well as uses a sensible projection. Solving these problems tends to be a headache when doing it all yourself in ggplot2. Note that I am the author of choroplethr, so I speak from experience :)

Another thing to point out is that you might want to overlay your choropleth over a reference map, such as those from google maps. I recently added that functionality to the latest version of choroplethr. But I haven't had a chance to update the package vignettes to explain how to use it. To get the default reference map just set `reference_map = TRUE`:

```
data(continental_us_states)
state_choropleth(df_pop_state, 
                 zoom = continental_us_states,
                 reference_map = TRUE)
```

[image]

If you wanted to use a different reference map (such as a satellite map), you can do that to. I just wrote a [blog post](http://www.arilamstein.com/blog/2015/10/08/how-to-change-the-reference-map-in-choroplethr/) on it. This is the most common question I got after implementing the reference map feature a few weeks ago.

Comment: Thanks! What if the state in my data does not exactly match with the state in "state.regions"? for example, I have "district of columbia" is missing.

Comment: By default missing regions appear black.

Comment: Thanks!! It is so great~

Comment: How do I add mouseover event on this choropleth? I did not find any thing that works. Seems like this just create a static image?

Comment: It just creates static images. That's the same limitation you have with ggplot2, which was your original question.

Comment: At this point I think your questions have gotten pretty far from your original question. I recommend opening new questions for subsequent questions. If you have choroplethr-specific questions you might want to ask on the choroplethr forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/choroplethr